# How can components be imported with "import * as {name}" syntax in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a react-native project, I would prefer to be able to import all my component like I do with types in my reducers.

I want to be able to write:
`import * as Components from '../components'`

so I went to my components folder, created an index.js file, imported all the basic components, and exported them like `export const ComponentExample1 = ComponentExample1` & `export const ComponentExample1 = <ComponentExample/>`. I figured there might be some naming related errors and thats what seems to have happened because I get the error:

```
Error: TransformErro SyntaxError: ......index.js: Identifier "ComponentExample1" has already been declared
```

All of my basic components are exported intra-component as `export default ComponentExample1`

How can I change my approach to effect my end desire?

Comment: A real piece of code would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-export your default exported components in index.js

Example:

```js
export { default as RoundButton } from './RoundButton'
export { default as Logo } from './Logo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete
    `export const ComponentExample1 = ComponentExample1`
and only keep
    `export const ComponentExample1 = <ComponentExample />`